# Jackson not de-serializing List property of domain class

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a `Category` domain model object, and am building a REST-style backend interface for an Angular app.  Currently, the `Category` object creation and persistence works as expected,  however the internal property of `categoryList` returns null on all GET requests.

My `Category` model:

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(
  name="findCategoryByName",
  query="select category FROM Category c WHERE c.category = :category"
)
@Table(name = "categories")
public class Category implements Serializable{

  @Id
  @Column(name = "category_id")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private int id;

  @Column
  private String category;

  @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "categories", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
  private List<Photo> photos;

  @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
  private Category parent;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
  @JsonDeserialize(as = ArrayList.class, contentAs = Category.class)
  private List<Category> categoryList;

  public Category() { }

}
```

My Jackson configuration in `AppConfig.java`:

```
public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jacksonMessageConverter(){
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.registerModule(new Hibernate4Module());
    converter.setObjectMapper(mapper);

    return converter;
}

@Override
public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterList){
    converterList.add(jacksonMessageConverter());
    super.configureMessageConverters(converterList);
}
```

The data is being retrieved via this method in my `CategoryRepository` implementation:

```
@Override
public List<Category> findAll(){
    List<Category> results = getEntityManager().createQuery("from Category").getResultList();
    return results;
}
```

When I send a GET request to `localhost:8080/admin/categories`, I get

```
{
    "id": 42,
    "category": "newCategory",
    "photos": null,
    "parent": {
        "id": 41,
        "category": "testCategory",
        "photos": null,
        "parent": null,
        "categoryList": null
    },
    "categoryList": null
}
```

However, if I set a breakpoint on `return results;` in the `FindAll()` method implementation, I can see that the `Category` parent `categoryList` field has a length of 1 and contains a reference to the `newCategory` category.

Why does this list value not show up on a GET request?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `@JsonDeserialize` annotation but your field is never initialized. `private List<Category> categoryList = new ArrayList<>()`?

Comment: @Bart, the field is indeed initialized as per the variable inspection in the debugger and as described at the end of my question.  I'm currently looking at how to manage bidirectional relationships at http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureBiDirReferences

Comment: Your repository may find results but that doesn't mean the `categoryList` field gets initialized. AFAIK when working with Hibernate one always needs to initialize collections.

Comment: List results keep returning null regardless of initialization